# Dynamic fields for my index not coming up in the list of fields

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I am trying to get the fields of my index using the below code snippet.

```
var fieldsList= DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.GetIndex("IndexName").Fields.ToList();
```

This is returning a string list with all fields defined in the index except the dynamic fields ( fields returned from _ ).

Here is the Map command for my index.

```
Map = products => 
    from product in product s
    select new
    {
        product.Title,
        product.Subject,
        product.From,
        _ = product.
            Attributes.Select(attribute => 
                    CreateField(attribute.Name, attribute.Value, false, true))
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

That is by design. The list of fields is the static fields that are in your index.
We don't try to find the dynamic ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

But when I look into the choose columns wizard in Raven studio once after executing the index, I am able to see all the fields in the select box. Please let us know if there is any way to retrieve those columns list through code.